# How can I prioritize one rsync process over another?

Tags: bash, rsync

I have two separate cronjobs running on a Red Hat instance. Both are copying log files from a remote server to the instance via rsync. The first cronjob runs `rsync-new.sh`, which copies any new log files (from today or yesterday) from various directories on the server. The second cronjob runs `rsync-backfill.sh`, which copies any log files older than yesterday. I separated the rsync processes so that the new files will always be copied quickly, and a large backfill job won't interfere with the copying of new files.

This generally works, except for the following case: if `rsync-backfill.sh` is already copying the old files from a folder, the `rsync-new.sh` won't copy its files until after `rsync-backfill.sh` has finished with the folder.

Is there any way to prioritize the rsync command from `rsync-new.sh` over the rsync command from `rsync-backfill.sh`? Or to at least let the rsync commands run in parallel so that the new files are always copied quickly?

Here's the general script structure:

**rsync-new.sh**

```sh
for SUBDIR in $(ls $SOURCEDIR)
do
  rsyc -zt \
    --exclude-from=$TRACKERFILE \
    --out-format="%n" \
    $SOURCEDIR/$SUBDIR/log-$TODAY*.log $DESTDIR/ | tee -a $TRACKERFILE
done

for SUBDIR in $(ls $SOURCEDIR)
do
  rsyc -zt \
    --exclude-from=$TRACKERFILE \
    --out-format="%n" \
    $SOURCEDIR/$SUBDIR/log-$YESTERDAY*.log $DESTDIR/ | tee -a $TRACKERFILE
done
```

**rsync-backfill.sh**

```sh
for SUBDIR in $(ls $SOURCEDIR)
do
  rsyc -zt \
    --exclude-from=$TRACKERFILE \
    --exclude="log-$TODAY*.log" \
    --exclude="log-$YESTERDAY*.log" \
    --out-format="%n" \
    $SOURCEDIR/$SUBDIR/log-*.log $DESTDIR/ | tee -a $TRACKERFILE
done
```

Comment: You can try playing with the `nice` command when runnig the scripts in cron be beware that those changes will impact the all system, see https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-issue, turns out it was just a coincidence that the new log files for one of the directories weren't syncing until after the backfill was complete (the new log files just happened to be much larger than the backfill files).

Cron runs jobs in isolated environments, so the rsync processes weren't interacting with each other.